# Combining continuous raster and point in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I have a layer that's a topographic map of a mountain range, represented by a continuous raster. I have another layer that is just points, representing where the summits are.

How can I use the raster layer to attach an elevation to each of these summit points based on location?

I'm using ArcMap 10.1.

I've tried using Extract value to points but it will not work, saying "Failed to add RASTERVALU to table".

Comment: Do you have the spatial analyst extension?

Comment: Yes. It won't let me post a 1 word comment so here's some filler text.

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times here. Did you take the time to search the forum before posting your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract Values to Points between rasters and point shapefiles of the same name](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112781/extract-values-to-points-between-rasters-and-point-shapefiles-of-the-same-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Here is what I would do.

Use the "Extract Values to Points" tool under "Extraction" which is in "Spatial Analyst Tools". You will use your point shapefile as the Input Point Feature and your continuous raster as the input Raster.

I think that may be all you need to do.

BTW instead of a 1-word comment, sometimes it is good policy to edit your question. It improves the value of the question.

Comment: I tried this and it's throwing the error "Failed to add field RASTERVALU to table." That field doesn't exist in the attribute table already so I don't know why it won't work.

Comment: That sounds like permission on the point layer. Try making a shapefile copy first ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I couldn't get Extract values to Points to work, but I was able to get the info I needed from Extract multi-values to points.